# Jasmine Javascript Testing

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Fairly new to coding and currently enrolled on a full stack course requiring me to perform testing on my Javascript. I am struggling to correctly write the code for my Jasmine test. Below is my Javascript and Jasmine code. Grateful for any help on this.

**JavaScript**

```
function changeBackground(x) {
    if (x.matches){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F6F6F6";
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)")
changeBackground(x) 
x.addListener(changeBackground)
```

**Jasmine**

```
describe("background-color", function() {      
   it("should change the background colour when screen size is less than 768px",function(){ 
      expect("changeBackground"(x)).toBe("white"); 
   });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrange, Act, Assert are the 3 A's for unit testing.

```
describe("background-color unit testing", function(){ 

    it('should test the background color and find white', function(){

      // Arrange. No code setup required

      //Act
      changeBackground(true);

      // Assert, query what the background color is then compare it to the expected value
      var color = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
      expect(color).toBe('white');
    })
});
```

Note: This has not been tested locally on my end but approximately what your end result should be.

EDIT:

Need to have a wrap of an it-statement within the describe block

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor()` is not a function

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Its a statement, not a function. The code has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can write a passing test for your function

```
describe("background-color", function(){ 
   it("should change the background colour when screen size is less than 768px",function(){ 
      var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      changeBackground(x)
      expect(document.body.style.backgroundColor).toBe('white'); 
   }); 
});
```

Of course your test depends on your test environment and on the size of your browser test window.
So if that's important you could
   - Make sure to configure your test runner so that the window is no larger than 768px
   - Refactor your function so that it does not depend anymore on the size of the window. I believe it would make your tests and code more robust.

For example:

```
function changeBackground(shouldChangeBackground) {
    if (shouldChangeBackground){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#F6F6F6";
    }
}

describe("background-color", function(){ 
   it("should change the background colour to white",function(){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
      changeBackground(true);
      expect(document.body.style.backgroundColor).toBe('white');
   }); 
});
```

And you can keep this environment specific requirement `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");` somewhere else.

This makes your code more testable which is a sign of a good architecture

Comment: Since the changeBackground does not return a value the expect(changeBackground()).toBe("white") will never be true.  You would need to have the changeBackground function return the color you want so you can expect it to be that color.  Or expect document.body.style.backgroundColor to be white.